# GIMP creates a folder on my desktop every time I open it

Tags: windows-10, gimp

I'm on Windows 10, and GIMP 2.10.10. Bit weird so bear with me for a second.

A few months ago I created a folder on my desktop named `decode`. Within the folder I placed a few files, including some images that I opened and edited or made with GIMP. A few days after that, I deleted the folder and all its contents.

For the next couple of weeks I noticed the folder kept reappearing on my desktop, empty, and I wasn't sure why. I thought it might've been windows's fault, but then I used [Process Monitor](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon) to see if I could pin down the exact culprit.

It turns out, every time I open GIMP now, it creates the folder again.

[image: Process Monitor log]

This can *probably* be fixed by reinstalling GIMP, but I'm interested to know *why* this would happen in the first place. Should this be reported as a GIMP bug?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Haven't you, at some point, set that exact folder as a working folder for GIMP? Or accepted it when suggested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Check Gimp's document history (*File>Open recent>Document history*) and see if there are still documents listed in that directory.
- Check if the folder was added in the left side panel of the Open/Save file dialogs.
- Check that in *Edit>Preferences>Folders* that this directory wasn't added to some Gimp config folders by mistake.

Comment: Indeed, it looks like I had added it as a font folder. Good call on that, and thanks for the answer.